# Windows 10 PCs do not recognize Samsung Ativ S connected via USB

Tags: usb, samsung-ativ-s

I have updated two PCs to Windows 10 (one Home, one Pro, both from Windows 8.1) and now none of them reacts when we connect my wife's Samsung Ativ S via USB. My Lumia 925 is recognized perfectly as before the update.

What can be happening here? An issue with drivers? Is there something that we can do to have the phone recognized again?

**Edit** based on answer. Tried the following:

- Multiple cables, multiple USB ports (the phone battery charges with all cacbles by the way).
- The Windows 10 Mobile Companion app. It just says "Your PC is ready, nothing else to setup".
- The devices manager. The phone is not listed (not even as an unknown device), and "search devices" yields nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found the solution and is so simple that I just can't believe I didn't think of it before...

...I just turned off and on the phone!! :-/

Comment: Nope. Turning the phone on and off does not work. Seems all phones that are Windows phones but are not Nokia are being phased out and becoming incompatible. After everything I still cannot connect my Samsung Ativ S Neo WP to my Win10 laptop since the last update.

Answer (score 2):

Tried using the phone on multiple USB ports using Multiple cables? Might also be a driver problem. Try removing the phone from the "Devices and printers" section in windows and then try to reconnect and see if it reads it. Windows 10 also comes with Mobile Companion. It may need to be setup for her phone for the first time to recognize it.

Here is more information on Phone Companion: http://betanews.com/2015/05/26/windows-10-phone-companion-app-is-a-game-changer-but-will-it-kill-windows-phone/

Video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXREpLEwgOY

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately nothing worked. I have updated the question.